# How to use the function `unregisterAdapterDataObserver` to cancel pending adapter updates - Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, observers

I am making some network calls to fetch images in my adapter. I want when new list is attached with the observer the pending network requests should not update the adapter. So whenever there  is a new list I want to cancel all the network calls created in the adapter. I found a function to check whether it has pending updates

```
depictionsRecyclerView.hasPendingAdapterUpdates()
```

but i don't know how to cancel all these updates.

Can someone please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you use for network call ? is this API call?

Comment: yes, i am calling an API

Comment: Then you can cancel all API calls whenever there is a new list available. Which library you have used for API calling?

Comment: just check if list is not new or length() > 0 than make a call

Comment: No, this is not the issue the list is already populated I am calling API for modified one attribute of the ArrayList. Hence checking list size won't work

Comment: I am using retrofit for APIs